# Missing properties in VS2015 Debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, com-object

Why can't I see properties of a COM object in debug mode in Visual Studio 2015. It works fine in VS2012. It's the same project so it should show the same??

Visual Studio 2012 (works fine)
[image: Visual Studio 2012 debug]

Visual Studio 2015 (properties gone)
[image: Visual Studio 2015 debug]

Comment: are you debugging from win 8.1 ?

Comment: @Webruster Windows 10
Edit: VS2012 on Windows 8.1 and VS2015 on Windows 10

Comment: In Tools --> Debugging--> enable the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators.

Comment: it would be better if you post the error in english

Comment: @Webruster Yay! You should write it as an answer so that I can mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to Change the settings Please change the Debbuging Settings

> In Tools -->Options---> Debugging--> enable the legacy C# and VB expression
>   evaluators.

Comment: Can you explain why this works and why it's necessary?

Comment: @DanFriedman Sorry for late Reply, after some research , actually i want to answer your question in two phases 1. Why this work and 2. why we need this or approaching this method .1.Why we need this approach :because actually there is is bug in existing debugging Engine, for old sake usage MSDN also kept legacy engine. they enabled this for these reason below  :  Continuation in Next Comment...

Comment: Continuation ...if You are using a .NET language other than C#, VB, or F# that provides its own Expression Evaluator (this includes managed C++) You want to enable Edit and Continue (EnC) for C++ projects while mixed mode debugging If these scenarios do not apply to you, there is no need for you to switch back to the legacy debug engine. Now 2.Why this work : as i already told you we are enabling our Old legacy debuggining Engine which supports the Expression Evaluator, so this is working  Continuing in Next Comment...

Comment: Continuation... . So i'm concluding with two points 1. Its a bug in existing Debug Engine .it might be fixed in future release and 2. MSDN might remove this old  legacy engine which we are using as fix  from the product Permanently in future.